# ReadyNAS 1100 Disk 3 keeps getting bad sectors

Tags: network-attached-storage, hardware, netgear

I am using a ReadyNAS 1100 and have had to replace the disk in slot 3 4 times over the past 1.5 years. The other disks have been perfect.

Disk 1 Power on hours: 26538

Disk 2 Power on hours: 26538

Disk 3 Power on hours: 1247

Disk 4 Power on hours: 7767

I could live with it for the first or second but 4 indicates problems to me.

Any idea what I should do to debug the issue or is it the case that the NAS is broken?

Comment: I would look into updating your NAS firmware.

Comment: Might be a faulty RAID slot.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff The NAS is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I faced the same issue, not with the NAS though, but with my machine.

My hard drives keeps on giving bad sectors after few days, and once I will replace it, it works fine and after few days, it will again alert me for bad sectors.

Later on I figured out that something was wrong with the hardware. Then I went and changed my Motherboard, and used the same hard drive for which I was getting the alerts for bad sectors and it worked just fine and working fine from last 9 months and that machine runs 24x7.

I am not expert in hardware but I believe the hard drive controlled must have gone bad and was causing the issue.

So, I am very sure that the issue is not with the hard disks but with the NAS.